# Concurrency issues while accessing data via reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, concurrency, locking

I'm currently writing a library that can be used to show the internal state of some running code (mainly fields and properties both public and private). Objects are accessed in a different thread to put their info into a window for the user to see. The problem is, there are times while I'm walking a long IList in which its structure may change. Some piece of code in the program being 'watched' may add a new item, or even worse, remove some. This of course causes the whole thing to crash.

I've come up with some ideas but I'm afraid they're not quite correct:

1. Locking the list being accessed while I'm walking it. I'm not sure if this would work since the IList being used may have not been locked for writing at the other side.
2. Let the code being watched to be aware of my existence and provide some interfaces to allow for synchronization. (I'd really like it to be totally transparent though).
3. As a last resort, put every read access into a try/catch block and pretend as if nothing happened when it throws. (Can't think of an uglier solution that actually works).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option number 3 may feel ugly, but this looks to be similar to the approach the Visual Studio watch windows use, and I would choose that approach.

In Visual Studio, you can often set a  watch on some list or collection and at a later point notice the watch simply displays an exception when it can't evaluate a certain value due to user or code state changes.

This is the most robust approach when dealing with such an open ended range of possibilities.  The fact is, if your watching code is designed to support as many scenarios as possible you will not be able to think of all situations in advance.    Handling and presenting exceptions nicely is the next best approach.

By the way, someone else mentioned that locking your data structures will work.  This is not true if the "other code" is not also using locks for synchronization.  In fact both pieces of code must lock the *same* synchronization object, very unlikely if you don't control the other code. (I think you mention this in your question, so I agree.)

Answer (score 4):

The only way you're going to keep things "transparent" to the code being monitored is to make the monitoring code robust in the face of state changes.

Some suggestions

1. Don't walk a shared list - make a copy of the list into a local List instance as soon (and as fast) as you can. Once you have a local (non-shared) list of instances, noone can monkey with the list.
2. Make things as robust as you can - putting every read into a try/catch might feel nasty, but you'll probably need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

While I like Bevan's idea of copying the list for local read access, if the list is particularly large, that may not be a truly viable option.

If you really need seamless, transparent, concurrent access to these lists, you should look into the Parallel Extensions for .NET library. It is currently available for .NET 2.0 through 3.5 as a CTP. The extensions will be officially included in .NET 4.0 along with some additional collections. I think you would be interested in the BlockingCollection from the CTP, which would give you that transparent concurrent access you need. There is obviously a performance hit as with any threaded stuff that involves synchronization, however these collections are fairly well optimized.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you don't want to have ANY dependency/requirement on the code being watched or enforce any constrains on how the code is written.

Although this is my favourite approach to code a "watcher", this causes you application to face a very broad range of code and behaviours, which can cause it to crash.

So, as said before me, my advice is to make the watcher "robust" in the first step. You should be prepared for anything going wrong anywhere in your code, because considering the "transparency", many things can potentially go wrong! (Be careful where to put your try/catch, entering and leaving the try block many times can have a visible performance impact)

When you're done making your code robust, next steps would be making it more usable and dodging the situations that can cause exceptions, like the "list" thing you mentioned. For example, you can check the watched object and see if it's a list, and it's not too long, first make a quick copy of it and then do the rest. This way you eliminate a large amount of the probability that can make your code throw.

Answer (score 0):

Locking the list will work, because it *is* being modified, as you've observed via the crashing :)

Seems to me, though, that I'd avoid locking (because it seems that your thread is only the 'watcher' and shouldn't really interrupt).

On this basis, I would just try and handle the cases where you determine missing things. Is this not possible?